# How do I solve the inverse image of this function along with this set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Let set $A=\{−3,−2,1\}$ and $h(x)=x^2−3$.
> What is the set of $h^{-1}(A)$?

- Instruction:List the items in between curly braces, just like the set A.

Here is my work:

- $h(x)=y$
- $y$ is the image of set $A$
- $y=x^2-3$
- $x^2=y+3$
- $x=\sqrt{y+3}$
- $h^{-1}(A)=\sqrt{a+3}$
- $\{\sqrt{-3+3},\sqrt{-2+3},\sqrt{1+3}\}$
- so the set is:
  $\{0,1,2\}$

> I feel like the logic is right, but where exactly am I going wrong?

Comment: $x^2=y+3\implies x=\sqrt{y+3}$ is incorrect.  Recall, $x^2 = 4$ is true when $x=2$ as well as is true when $x=-2$.  It should have been $x^2=y+3\implies x = \pm \sqrt{y+3}$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

We want to find
$$
h^{-1}(A)=\{x \in \mathbb{R} ; h(x) \in A \}=\{x \in \mathbb{R} ; x^2-3 \in \{-3,-2,1\} \}
$$
But notice this is equal to
$$
h^{-1}(A)=\{x \in \mathbb{R} ; x^2-3=-3 \} \bigcup \{x \in \mathbb{R} ; x^2-3=-2 \} \bigcup \{x \in \mathbb{R} ; x^2-3=1 \}
$$
$$
h^{-1}(A)=\{x \in \mathbb{R} ; x^2=0 \} \bigcup \{x \in \mathbb{R} ; x^2=1 \} \bigcup \{x \in \mathbb{R} ; x^2=4 \}
$$
$$
h^{-1}(A)=\{0\} \bigcup \{ \pm1 \} \bigcup \{\pm2 \}
$$
$$
h^{-1}(A)=\{0,\pm1,\pm2\}
$$